# Distinct not working in DRF sqlite database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Distinct not working.I am using sqlite in backend

```
class getPatient(generics.ListAPIView):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Patient.objects.all().distinct()
        serializer = PatientSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({'patient': serializer.data})
```

I tried :

queryset = Patient.objects.distinct("name").all()

queryset = Patient.objects.values('name').distinct()

queryset = Patient.objects.all().distinct()

Nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

I have to mention that backend sqlite doesn't support distinct. Consider changing for postgresql as the most supported for django backends.

First you have to order objects by the field if you want to distinct.
I have included you the documentation and example.

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows.

[django distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Try out, by putting one of your model field. ex. "name".

```
class getPatient(generics.ListAPIView):

def list(self, request):
    queryset = Patient.objects.order_by('name_field').distinct('name_field')
    serializer = PatientSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response({'patient': serializer.data})
```

Comment: thanks bluebles for your response but now it's showing DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend error

Comment: Please check
`Patient.objects.values('name').annotate(name=Min('name'))`
It's not recomened solution but the only that I know for sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to use `order_by` and `distinct` in **sqlite** **database together** since in documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) it is mentioned for example that **those works only in PostgreSQL**.

[image: Documentation Screen Shot]